# Reverse CSS triangle gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

[I have this gradient:](https://jsfiddle.net/d21m1mn3/)

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  background: linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 63%, white 63%),
              linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 63%, white 63%),
              linear-gradient(to top, blue, blue);
}
```

I want to know a) how do I flip it so it's coming from the top and b) how to rewrite without the third part `(to top, blue, blue)` since I just want a single color and it seems wrong this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, you can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/d21m1mn3/1/)

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  background: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 63%, white 63%),
              linear-gradient(-120deg, transparent 63%, white 63%),
              blue;
}
```

For the second part, try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/d21m1mn3/3/)

```
div {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
}
```

Hope this will help you ..

Comment: The first part covers both questions. I don't know why you have the second part there?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with just two `linear-gradient` images by setting the appropriate `background-size` and `background-position` for the images (like in the below snippet).

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 49.5%, blue 50.5%), 
              linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.5%, blue 50.5%);
              /* the difference in color stops is to produce smoother edges */
  background-size: 50% 95%; /* X size should be 50%, Y size can be as you wish */
  background-position: left top, right top; /* don't change */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* don't change */
}

/* just for demo */
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
div:nth-child(2), div:nth-child(4) { width: 150px; }
div:nth-child(2), div:nth-child(3) { height: 150px; }
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I've changed the gradient to the `to [side] [side]` syntax because it helps in achieving responsive output. (*You can refer to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185527/background-with-gradient-responsive/37187994#37187994) for a detailed explanation about why that change helps.*)

---

In the below snippet, I've given two different colors for the gradient so that you could visually see what is happening.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 49.5%, blue 50.5%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.5%, green 50.5%);
  background-size: 50% 95%;
  background-position: left top, right top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```