# CSS gradient split div into to halves from left bottom to top right

Tags: css, gradient

Is there possibility to achieve it only with gradient property?
How it should look like:

[image: how it should look like]

I've tried this but it does not split it correctly.

```
@mixin content-cropped-shape($color, $color2){
  background: $color;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,$color 0%, $color 50%, $color2 50%, $color2 100%);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, use the `to [side] [side]` syntax like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185527/background-with-gradient-responsive/37187994#37187994) instead of angles. That answer also has an explanation on why the angled gradient doesn't always produce a triangle. You may find it helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do. With 'to right bottom' and remove the angle.

```css
div {
  background: rgb(255,255,255);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(255,0,4,1) 50%,rgba(249,0,4,1) 100%); 
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```