# Speciying Angle in CSS3 Linear Gradients

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am using CSS3 linear gradient as background, currently I'm using left to right gradient, but I want to specify gradient from bottom left to top right but not able to figure out what should be the value of angle for that.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,#7E0F4B, #1A5865);
```

[image: Linear Gradient left to right]

Answer (score 2):

When the gradient needs to go from side(s) to side(s), its always better to use the `to [side] [side]` syntax instead of using angles. You'll find a detailed explanation on why this syntax is better than the angles in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185527/background-with-gradient-responsive/37187994#37187994).

For this particular case, you sort of have your answer in the question itself. The gradient needs to go from bottom-left to top-right and so the first parameter to the `linear-gradient` function should be `to top right`.

CSS gradient syntax supports both the `to [side]` syntax and the `to [side] [side]` (in other words the *to corner*) syntax. Below is an extract from the [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#linear-gradients) (emphasis is mine):

> **using keywords**
>
> If the argument is to top, to right, to bottom, or to left, the angle of the gradient line is 0deg, 90deg, 180deg, or 270deg, respectively.
>
> ***If the argument instead specifies a corner of the box such as to top left***, the gradient line must be angled such that it points into the same quadrant as the specified corner, and is perpendicular to a line intersecting the two neighboring corners of the gradient box. This causes a color-stop at 50% to intersect the two neighboring corners (see example).

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #7E0F4B, #1A5865);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```